# Sort of Fixed : Box2D Light, Player in center ( LibGDX )

Tags: java, libgdx, box2d, lighting, light

I am using LibGDX, and Box2D ( with the addon Box2D Light ).

I wanted to put my player ( with the light ) in the middle. It didn't work.
I though by just moving the OrthographicCamera and updating my rayHandler's CombinedMatrix it would work.

But it doesnt:
[Pic1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/h5hl0ift8btqm0x/Box2D%20Problem.png) or [Mirror](http://www.mediafire.com/view/rev6jkpo8oc8ns8/Box2D%20Problem%20%281%29.png)

My player gets drawn in the center.
but i couldn't get my light to be in the center and the whole Box2D scene around it
I tried multiple things but all failed badly.
So i have no idea what i can do now.

I am trying to acheive this:
[Pic1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/v46xs9gnkz39r3w/Goal.png) or [Mirror](http://www.mediafire.com/view/y34dn5alfc6zfdj/Goal.png)

As you can see, the light is on the player, and it moves with him also, and they are both in the middle ( made in Game Maker )

Edit : 
Ok, so i got it working, but i still have no idea why,
'lvlControl.mat.camera.position.set(MazeStartX+player.PlayerX-16, MazeStartY+player.PlayerY-16, 0);
        lvlControl.mat.camera.update();

```
    light.setPosition(MazeStartX+(player.PlayerX),MazeStartY+(player.PlayerY));
    rayHandler.setCombinedMatrix(lvlControl.mat.camera.combined);
    rayHandler.updateAndRender();'
```

But i have an issue with that,
It might increase lag alot more on android because it updates two times the camera ( one before so i can render my sprite batch correctly. )
So yeah, i'll test it but i don't think this is a permenant solution,
I will try to have a better solution, but for now it works :)
Aniway thanks everybody!

Comment: for me, those pictures aren't working (the dropbox ones)

Comment: Sorry, fixed, i added new links, they should work for you.

Comment: Post the relevant parts of your code :)